# What is the best way to move site to new domain without losing google page rank

Tags: domain, http-headers, google

I just bought new domain for my web page.
Is it good to use php redirection to the new domain and what are the exact headers that I must send to google bot to just renew the address and keep the page rank without loosing position in search results for the specific keyword ?
Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

301 permanent redirect.

It is not full proof, but it is the best approach.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm reading something about '301 VS 303' What is you opinion?

Comment: You can probably set up the redirect and, after Google notices it, you can delete the old domain. _NOTE: That's just my guess._

Answer (score 3):

have a look at http://www.google.com/webmasters/
once you set your site up in there, they have a whole page of info about changing domain names,etc

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just found this topic http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=83106 If you got better post it.

Comment: Also found this http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=83105 Thnks again and have a good night :)

Answer (score 1):

You should also do a change of address after you've done your 301 redirects, so Google knows your intentions:
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/83106?hl=en

The 301 redirects should be mapped page - to - page, so that the content on each indexed page is relevant to the content on the mapped page on the new domain.